# Insertion Error Java ArrayIndex out of bounds

Tags: java, insertion-sort

Running this code:

```
public static int[] insertionSort(int[] array) {
    for (int j = 1; j < array.length; j++) {
        int cur = array[j];
        int prev = j - 1;
        while ( (prev > -1)  && (array[prev] > cur)) {

            array[cur] = array[prev];
            prev--;
        }
        array[prev + 1] = cur;
    }
    return array;

}
```

I get an Indexoutofbounds error on array[cur] = array[prev];

Here is my test case:

```
    int[] array = { 23, 5, 3, 5, 34, 2};
```

Why the error? The logic I think is good

Comment: If you applied basic debugging (like printing `cur` and `prev`) you wouldn't have to ask this question...

Answer (score 3):

```
 int cur = array[j];// So, 'cur' will have any number may be out of bound
```

In your loop you are using `array[cur] = array[prev];` and consider `cur = 23`  that is out of bound. Basically, `cur` meant for current index but you are storing current element in it.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the while loop and i hope this is working fine .

```
while ((prev >= 0) && (array[prev] < cur)) 
{
   array[prev + 1] = array[prev];
   prev--;
}
```

Comment: i checked in console project  for (int j = 1; j < array.Length; j++)
            {
                int cur = array[j];
                int prev = j - 1;
                while ((prev >= 0) && (array[prev] < cur))
                {
                    array[prev + 1] = array[prev];
                    prev--;
                }
                array[prev + 1] = cur;
            }
            return array;

Comment: i know this is bad formatting , but this method is not working there ?? if yes then give me your code .

Comment: I don't say, it's not working anymore, I've just wrongly read your snippet,  because the formatting. And upvoted your answer yet